# flex Support in linux

Tags: linux, apache-flex, flex4, adobe

I am developing p2p application using RTFMP and flex.I am doing some research on this using adobe cirrus server and developed flex client application on windows and its working correctly.
Now I want to create client using flex on Linux machine.the constraint is client should  run all type of Linux Red hat, Ubuntu etc.

Will flex development is supported on all for of Linux or not?

What development is required for the flex development on Linux?

Is there any IDE available for flex development?

Comment: Thanks your quick reply.I know RTMFP.I wanted to know linux support for flex sdk4.0 or api and development environment on Linux.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the protocol is named RTMP, or Real Time Messaging Protocol.  There is no F.  ( @ypnos @Chris_VR )

Comment: I stand corrected on the protocol front.  RTMFP stands for Real Time MEssaging Flow Protocol and is different than RTMP.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTMFP

Comment: U r right.It was spelling mistake.it is RTMFP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop with Flex on Linux using the command line compiler available in the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK).

Flash Builder, Adobe's eclipse based IDE is not supported on Linux.  But, you can search out alternate IDEs.  [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) is one that has linux support.  I thought that [IntelliJ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fidea%2F&rct=j&q=IntelliJ&ei=nkIvTdS9K5CdgQeAjP1a&usg=AFQjCNF5HA_WodXGzI5OKtfhBRYkTvaRPA&cad=rja) did too.  The Flex support in IntelliJ was demonstrated at Max and is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has an [ActionScript 3 mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ActionScriptMode) and a binding for the [Flex debugger](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFlexDebugger). A Makefile to configure [mxmlc](http://www.docsultant.com/site2/articles/flex_cmd.html) is simple enough:

```
MXMLC = /home/foo/flex_sdk/bin/mxmlc
MFLAGS =

TARGETS  = hello.swf

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(TARGETS)

.SUFFIXES:      .as .swf
.as.swf:
        $(MXMLC) $(MFLAGS) $<
```

Here is a sample Rakefile:

```
task :default do
  DEV_ROOT = "/Users/base/flex_development"
  PUBLIC = "#{DEV_ROOT}/bin"
  FLEX_ROOT = "#{DEV_ROOT}/src"
  system "/Developer/SDKs/Flex/bin/mxmlc --show-actionscript-warnings=true --strict=tr
ue -file-specs #{FLEX_ROOT}/App.mxml"
  system "cp #{FLEX_ROOT}/App.swf #{PUBLIC}/App.swf"
end
```

and a sample Ant task:

```
<target name="compileMain" description="Compiles the main application files.">
    <echo>Compiling '${bin.dir}/main.swf'...</echo>
    <java jar="${FLEX_HOME}/lib/mxmlc.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="+flexlib=${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" />
        <arg value="-file-specs='${src.dir}/main.mxml'" />
        <arg value="-output='${bin.dir}/main.swf'" />
    </java>
</target>
```

**References**

- [Flex 3 Cookbook: Chapter 21. Compiling and Debugging](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/pdfs/ora_flex3_ckbk_ch21.pdf)
- [Using the Flex Compiler SHell (FCSH)](http://projectsprouts.org/2011/01/18/using-fcsh.html)
- [Apache Flex® - Third-Party Tools & Solutions](http://flex.apache.org/community-3rdparty.html)